Enterprise logging 5.0 file rename
I am new to Microsoft enterprise library logging and i am using one in my current project. I see it is creating new files on the first logging entry renaming old by adding todays time stamp. How can i override this behavior to appending the date to filename?
Try changing the filename at the runtime

Not sure what led you to Enterprise Library, but it has been deprecated a long while ago, https://github.com/microsoftarchive/enterprise-library so if you don't plan to support yourself on such a library in the future please switch to a more up-to-date library with similiar features. The search engines can show you quite a few good ones.
